# Understanding VS 2010 Module Window

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I view the Modules window in VS2010 with my code running, my code i.e. user code = yes it is shown as Optimized = No.

Should I be able to make my code run as optimized and if so how?

Additionally, I see some modules loaded which don't make sense e.g. System.Data.OracleClient.dll, why? I'm not even using oracle within my application??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about :) "Optimization" is related to the JIT. See this article [JIT Optimization and Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241594%28VS.80%29.aspx) for more information.

The fact that System.Data.OracleClient is loaded seems more strange if you're not using Oracle, but VS 2010 has that Data Source tool window that probably hits it even when snobody is using it.

Comment: thanks for prompt response. The optimization part I accept but the Module window indicates that its my process that is hosting the System.Data.Oracle.dll??

Comment: That's strange. I suppose some other assembly you're using is loading it indirectly (orm, ado.net code, etc.)

Comment: thanks again. Yes, obviously something is loading it, I'm using EF4 but I'm sure that just works with SQL Server. Will not lose any sleep over it! Thanks.